# How to show this tag $\mathbbmss{x}$ in PostScript or PS format?

Tags: symbols

`\mathbbmss{x}` - This tag in viewable in DVI format but after creating a PostScript or PS format, the symbol will disappear.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Answer (score 3):

The font `bbm` is available only in `METAFONT` format. This means that, when you use that font for the first time, a bitmap has to be created for each glyph, compiling the `METAPOST` sources.

Usually this happens "automagically", so that when executing `latex` on your document, the font is compiled, the bitmap is created, and the font-geometry files are created too. TeX only needs the later, in order to know how much space each character requires, but the actual bitmap which shows the character is not used by TeX, but by the "driver" which has to convert the `.dvi` file into a "viewable" version.

You use two different "drivers" to see the resulting `.dvi`. One is your dvi-viewer, the other is the program `dvips` (I guess). From your question, it appears that the dvi-viewer has not problems in finding the files which contains the bitmaps which compose the font, since it correctly displays your char. However, the `dvi->ps` conversion program is unable to find those files, since the resulting PS doesn't show the char.

Usually the problem is due to the fact that the dvi-previewer and the `dvi->ps` programs use different versions of the fonts, because they need different resolution. But again this is usually solved "automagically", because `dvips` calls `metafont` in order to get the required fonts at the required resolution.

So apparently your problem has to do with the configuration of `dvips`. These kind of problems are usually difficult to solve. I would suggest you to compile with `pdflatex` instead and see if the problem vanishes (although probably it will not, because usually `pdflatex` and `dvips` share part of the font configuration).

I have to say that in my system both `latex`, `dvips` and `pdflatex` work perfectly, as the following MWE shows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bbm}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
Testing bbm fonts: $\mathbbmss{x}$
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]